# Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS in viewdidunload

Tags: iphone

I am getting exception on few of my ViewControllers when I go through browsing the application.

The exception is occurring in viewdidunload, I think this is due to memory warning.
The following line gets an exception which are the IBOulet objects.

```
self.LabelDistance = nil;
self.distanceSlider = nil;
```

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```
[self.labelDistance release];
[self.distanceSlider release];
```

instead. Also, you shouldn't be releasing ivars in `viewDidUnload`, release them in `dealloc`. If the problem persists, run the static analyzer (Build menu >> Build and Analyze), it is generally good at finding memory related issues.

Comment: You should release IBOutlets in viewDidUnload.  Because when the view is loaded again it will set them.

Comment: @rickharrison - Although if they're properties constructed with the `retain` setter semantic, they'll be released in the synthesized setter when the new value is set. At which point, I think you'd run the risk of over-releasing them, if you did it in viewDidUnload too.

Comment: @Dan Ray - Well if you do self.iboutlet = nil in viewDidUnload than the memory will be reclaimed by the system. That also allows a safe call of resetting the outlet in viewDidLoad again.

Comment: @rickharrison: I'm saying, I think that shouldn't be necessary, as long as the properties are of the "retain" style. Just assigning to that property a second time (as long as you use the @synthesized setter, possibly via dot notation) will release the previous content before it assigns.

Comment: voted down because you should not call [self.xxx release]. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5737438/119321

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to set this to nil?

If it's a `@property (retain) UILabel * labelDistance;`  (and synthesized), then just `release` it in `dealloc`. Or do you fiddle with that ivar around?

One note: your variable and property should begin with a lower letter "l".