# Releasing a property with self.property - Errors in the Analyzer

Tags: ios, xcode4, properties, analysis

I've an UIViewController with a property

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *speakerFetchResults;
```

Then I set the property in viewWillAppear with

```
 self.speakerFetchResults = [[[self.speakerViewContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

and want to release it again in the UIViewController's dealloc method with

```
[self.speakerFetchResults release];
```

But, if I analyze my file I get on the [self.speakerFetchResults release]; the following warning:

Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller.

Furthermore (I've testet it out) I get this message on all

[self.anything release]

issues.

So I'm a little bit confused and removing all "self." in this releases or in general cause a lot of errors in the programm. So I think the analyzer is wrong, but I just want to ask you for some help.

What do you think?

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't [call release on the object returned by the getter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262268/why-shouldnt-i-use-the-getter-to-release-a-property-in-objective-c) (the getter may have side effects, custom logic, return autoreleased objects, etc. so you can not assume that `[self.speakerFetchResults release]` and `[speakerFetchResults release]` have the same results).

You can simply do:

```
self.speakerFetchResults = nil; // this releases the old value
```

Or, in dealloc, where the use of accessors is discouraged:

```
[speakerFetchResults release];
```