# Got warning "Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller"

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

When 'Analyse', Got warning "Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller" in this. (xCode 4.1+)

I can understant that it's better to "kill" an object from it's proper class, but is there a way to do it from outside without a warning?

Thanks!

```
NSLog(@"--[%s:%d]",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
myAppDelegate* appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   if (appDelegate.referencesPopup != nil) {
        [appDelegate.referencesPopup release]; // warning
        appDelegate.referencesPopup = nil;  
   }      
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, the way in which you are acquiring the object being stored in `referencesPopup`, you did not allocate it yourself or retain it. In that case, you are not responsible for releasing it. You can simply set the ivar to nil.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks, but i'm still confused.  If I reallocate the object after the appDelegate.referencePopUp=Nil, I will create a memory leak, no? (referencePupUp =nil doesn't means that retaincount decrement)

Comment: How is `referencesPopup` assigned initially? Do you allocate an object or acquire an object from somewhere else? If the latter, then setting `referencesPopup` to nil is harmless; if you did not allocate (or copy) an object then you are not responsible for releasing it.

Comment: appDelegate.referencesPopup = [[References alloc] init];

Comment: Ok, so you are allocating it, and because you are using the setter method to access `referencesPopup`, you're getting a `retain` done for you. So, in your code above, you do NOT need to call release yourself because by using the setter method again to set `referencesPopup` to nil, you get a `release` done for you. So that is why your call to release is redundant.

Comment: appDelegate.referencesPopup = [[References alloc] init]
Hi, based on your comments, this can have a memory leak, no?

[[References alloc] init] = retaincout++
and appDelegate.referencesPopup = retaincount++ (user the setter =implicit retain)

So, correct line should be (?)
 
appDelegate.referencesPopup = [[References alloc] init]autorelease];


Still starting to understand, and ARC comings... :)

Comment: Although it seems more efficient to combine the assignment of a variable (through a setter, here) with the allocation and init of an object, that is actually the wrong way to do it (without ARC). You should have 3 distinct statements: `References *r = [[References alloc] init]`, `appDelegate.referencesPopup = r`, and `[r release]`. The middle statement invokes a setter method and you get a `retain` for free. Using autorelease in this mix would be wrong as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just set the property to `nil`, there is no need to release it here, as the analyzer is telling you. If you didn't retain it, don't release it.

Also, you shouldn't call `release` on something that is returned by a dot notation getter. This has been discussed extensively here: [Why shouldn't I use the getter to release a property in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262268/why-shouldnt-i-use-the-getter-to-release-a-property-in-objective-c/7262360#7262360)