# NSDictionary memory leak while assigning value to it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

As i have finished my iOS App and was removing the memory leaks,
I found that instrument was showing leak while assigning the values to it.

In the .h file i have declared the NSdictionary feedData with the property(nonatomic, retain).

I have one more class WebServiceController which returs the NSdictionary.

Here is my code.
In the .m file

```
if ([nid rangeOfString:@","].location == NSNotFound) 
{

    NSArray *data = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:nid,[NSNumber numberWithInt:0],[NSNumber numberWithInt:0],delegate1.myCity,nil];
    WebServiceController *wsct=[[WebServiceController alloc]init];
    wsct.delegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    feedData=[wsct getTimelineFeed:data];
    NSLog(@"feed data is--->%@",feedData);
    [wsct release];

}
```

The code "feedData=[wsct getTimelineFeed:data];" is giving memory leak.

here is the function that is returning the NSDictionary.

-(NSDictionary*)MyTimelineFeed:(NSArray*)data

{

```
if(![delegate sessionId] )  return nil;    

XMLRPCRequest *request = [[XMLRPCRequest alloc] initWithHost:[NSURL URLWithString:ENDPOINT]];





NSMutableArray * postParams = [NSMutableArray array];

NSString * method = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"timeline.getFeedItems"];

[postParams addObject:[delegate sessionId] ];  





for (int i = 0;  i < [data count]; i++) {

    [postParams addObject:[data objectAtIndex:i]];

}



[request setMethod:method withObject:postParams];

XMLRPCResponse *nodeSaveResponse = [XMLRPCConnection sendSynchronousXMLRPCRequest:request];


[request release];  


if([nodeSaveResponse isKindOfClass:[NSError class]])

    return nil;


NSMutableDictionary * dict = [nodeSaveResponse object];

if ([dict isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
    //NSLog(@"Error found");
    return nil;
}

return dict;
```

}

pls help.

Comment: Is WebServiceController a class you have written? Can you include the implementation of getTimelineFeed in the question?

Comment: i have added the function in my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that this method:

```
feedData=[wsct getTimelineFeed:data];
```

Is returning a NSDictionary with a `retain` count of 1, which should not be the case, because according to the memory management rules for Cocoa only methods that start with `new` or `alloc` or contain `copy` should return objects with a `retain` count of 1.

Change your method to this:

```
newTimelineFeed
```

And it should be good to go :)

Comment: Why there is a need to change the function name.what if i change it to MyTimelineFeed, as the NSDictionary returned by the function is saved by the object feedData, for which i already declare its property(nonatomic,retain).

Comment: @AjeetPratapMaurya That is because if the method returns a retained object the memory management rules for Cocoa indicate it should be named that way. Additionally although your property feedData is retain you are accessing the ivar directly and not thru the setter, to use the setter you must use self.feedData = newData;

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the line

```
self.feedData =[wsct getTimelineFeed:data];
```

Not

```
feedData =[wsct getTimelineFeed:data];
```

I can't see any leaks in the rest of the code but there is potential here to lose a reference to a previously allocated variable as you are not going through the synthesized accessor - using self.feedData will release any previous value held in the ivar before retaining the new one, assigning a value to the ivar directly will not do this.

Answer (score -2):

You can change the line:

```
feedData = [wsct getTimelineFeed:data];
```

With:

```
feedData = [[wsct getTimelineDeed:data] retain];
```

Just remember to release feedData when it is no longer needed.

Comment: I guess the "very right" answer would have been to consider using 

[self.feedData release];
self.feedData = [wsct getTimelineFeed:data]; 
[data release];

as the property has been defined as retain, so why don't you just use it.

Also don't forget to release the feedData value during the class dealloc

Comment: @SebastienThuilliez - no, that isn't "very right". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262268/why-shouldnt-i-use-the-getter-to-release-a-property-in-objective-c/7262360#7262360 for an excellent discussion

Comment: Extra retains aren't going to stop memory _leaks_