# Should releasing an object and setting it to nil be atomic?

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, cocoa-touch

I'm new to Objective C.  I see in many iPhone/iPad applications that after releasing an object, it would then be set to nil.

```
[self.obj release]
self.obj = nil;
```

I assume this is done so as not to leave the pointer to reference a memory location that is now deallocated. Now assume the following situation:

```
//Thread #1 code
..some code
..some code
[self.obj release]
                  -------> Thread #2 runs //Thread #2 code
                                          ..some code
                                          if (self.obj){
                                            some code
                                          }
self.obj = nil;   <----- Thread #1 runs
```

I was wondering if this situation possible? And if it is, is there a way to make the release/nil atomic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is actually not entirely correct

```
[self.obj release]
self.obj = nil;
```

you should write simply

```
self.obj = nil;
```

which will call the setter that will release the previous instance.

Comment: This is correct provided the nonatomic attribute isn't set on the obj property.  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html

Comment: Yes, i realize.. Look below at my comment @DBD 's post. I made the properties non atomic. Thanks tho :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it could blow up. Consider your code example.

```
[self.obj release];
self.obj = nil;
```

You use `self.obj` which means you are referencing accessor/mutators methods instead of accessing your object directly. Chances are you'd declare "obj" as a retained property. Your .h would be something like...

```
@property (retain) Something *obj;
```

and your .m

```
@synthesize obj;
```

If you later release your object by using the methods created by your `@synthesize` you are safe.

```
[self setObj:nil];
// or equally valid
self.obj = nil;
// Below is (almost) identical way to access, release and nil the variable directly.
// The major difference is you don't multi-threaded protection of your property
// declaration (explained below).
[obj release];
obj = nil;
```

If you look back at the property I specified above you'll notice I didn't put in the very commonly seen `nonatomic`. It wasn't by accident. Take a look at Apple's [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1)

> Properties are atomic by default so that synthesized accessors provide robust access to properties in a multithreaded environment—that is, the value returned from the getter or set via the setter is always fully retrieved or set regardless of what other threads are executing concurrently.

Comment: Thanks, I have a chosen a combination of yours and Anders's answer above.  I will use **self.obj = nil;** which will invoke the setter to release the old value. Also, i will set the @property to be atomic like you said. I chose his answer tho.. only one correct answer can be chosen ><

Answer (score 1):

You can surround both operations in an @synchronized block to ensure that both operations complete before leaving the block:

```
@synchronized(lockObject)
{
    [self.obj release];
    self.obj = nil;
}
```

Provided that any other threads that might access that variable also synchronize around the same lock object, you shouldn't run into any issues.

Comment: Good point. Thanks, but i went with setting he property as atomic as mentioned below.

Comment: Sending `release` to the result of an accessor call isn't the best idea. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262268/why-shouldnt-i-use-the-getter-to-release-a-property-in-objective-c