# Is that the correct way to deal with ivars?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have read a lot of topics about getters and setters. I know what they are and why are useful. Different source claim's different ways to release the ivars. Here begins my confusion

```
@interface CoolClass : NSObject
{
  NSString *name;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@end

@implementation CoolClass
@synthesize name = _name;

-(id)init
{
  if(super = [self super])
  {
     self.name = @"Jo";
  }
  return self;
}

-(void)dealloc
{
  [self.name release], self.name = nil;
}
@end
```

Is that the correct way to release/free ivars ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I use the getter to release a property in objective-c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262268/why-shouldnt-i-use-the-getter-to-release-a-property-in-objective-c)

Comment: @Profo Post answer: I missed that you'd written `super = [self super]` -- it should be `self = [super init]`

Comment: if((super = [super init])) should also be written with double (( )) to avoid a compiler warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use accessors most of the time, but not in partially constructed states because they can have [negative side-effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932677/initializing-a-property-dot-notation/5932733#5932733). Here's how it's done:

```
- (id)init
{
  if((self = [super init])) {
     // self.name = @"Jo"; << don't use accessors in initializer

     _name = [@"Jo" copy]; << good
  }
  return self;
}
// added for another variation:
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)inName
{
  if((self = [super init])) {
     _name = [inName copy];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    // don't use accessors in dealloc
    // don't release the result of a getter (release the result of the retained or copied result)
    // [self.name release], self.name = nil;  

    // instead:
    [_name release], _name = nil;
    [super dealloc]; << compiler should have warned you about this one
}
```

*Note: In the case of `init`, the string literal is an immortal and it won't matter if you copy it because the copy just returns itself. My preference is to just 'copy' the immortal for clarity, although it's unnecessary.*

Comment: why you shouldn't use accessors in the initializer's ?

Comment: What do you mean by "immortal" ?

Comment: @meccan here's an example i wrote up which demonstrates some of the things that can go wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932677/initializing-a-property-dot-notation/5932733#5932733

Comment: @Profo `NSString` literals (e.g. `@"Hi there!"`) live for the life of your program and are never dealloc'ed.

Comment: @meccan I use them quite a bit myself too, but I've been writing objc for 9 years now so i've made enough mistakes that it doesn't affect me terribly often. you may like this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086736/why-would-you-use-an-ivar/9086811#9086811

Comment: @profo, it's still good practice to retain/copy/release it as normal because if it changes from a literal to something else you wouldn't want to introduce a leak.

Comment: @Justin i just checked som objC / Cocoa Developer Book from Apress and the authors often user the accessor instead the ivar in the initializer... crazy =)

Comment: @meccan I've worked with people who have *insisted* on it. not just that but also things like "just call `viewDidUnload` in `dealloc` to zero the IBOutlets. if we notice an issue in development…".

Comment: @Justin last Question: What is the best way to set the properties in an initializer if you extend from e.g. UILabel, because you can't access the iVars in the initializer...

Comment: @meccan for self's properties, i just use one of the designated initializers, set up my ivars in init, and leave the rest to the client. in special cases where I really really want this functionality, I'll use a convenience constructor to accomplish this.

Comment: @Justin you mean a Class Method where you return a autoreleased object? e.g. -(MyLabel*)labelWithText:(NSString *)text { MyLabel *l = [[MyLabel alloc ]init]; l.text = text; return [l autorelease];} ??

Comment: @meccan yup. either class method: `+ (MyLabel *)labelWithText:` or `+ (MyLabel *)newLabelWithText:`

Comment: and why is apple using the behavior in the docus? Is this the wrong way? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/AddingBehaviortoaCocoaProgram/AddingBehaviorCocoa.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH5-SW35

Comment: @meccan i can't speak for apple. however, the approach in the sample could be a source of bugs -- the implementations can change at any time, and we've no guarantee it would be without side effects. it also depends on what your implementations override and implement. when programs reach a certain amount of complexity, it is best (IMO) to observe the boundaries of defined order and behavior. a lot of people think i'm over-cautious -- 98% success rate of a program is just not good enough (IMO). programs that make frequent exceptions require a lot of maintenance (YMMV).

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would advise:

```
@interface CoolClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@end

@implementation CoolClass
@synthesize name = _name;

-(id)init
{
  if(super = [self super])
  {
     self.name = @"Jo";
  }
  return self;
}

-(void)dealloc
{
  [_name release];
  [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Notes:

1. There is no need to explicitly declare ivars inside { ... } in your header. They will be created automatically when you synthesise your property. Explicit ivars are a legacy concept that are no longer needed since about iOS 3.
2. You should not use self.name in the dealloc as this calls the getter method, which may do additional work beyond merely fetching the ivar. Normally it's good practice to use the getter method, but in the dealloc you should release the ivar directly
3. It is good practice to set ivars to nil after releasing them, but again in the dealloc this in not necessary because no code is ever executed after dealloc, so the pointer won't be referenced again.
4. Normally (outside of the dealloc), if you wish to release an ivar you should set it to nil using the setter like this: self.name = nil; that will automatically release it and set it to nil. This is equivalent to [_name release], _name = nil;

Comment: @Justin notice above that self.name = @"Jo" is incorect, can you confirm that ?

Comment: @Nick Regarding #3: dangling references in `dealloc` bite. it's uncommon, but it happens.

Comment: Only if the dealloc of a subclass violates the "don't do any work" rule. For example if you call a setter/getter method that references other ivars. If the only thing you put in dealloc is release statements and deregister from notification and KVO observers (like you're supposed to), you'll be fine.

Comment: @NickLockwood that's not how all real object graphs are constructed - there are still corner cases such as weak references.

Comment: Fair enough. It's not a problem I've run into but I can see how it could happen theoretically. Along the same lines, you shouldn't set ivars directly in init, because init may call another inherited init that also sets the same ivar.

Comment: @NickLockwood that's not an issue here - I always use `@private` ivars and never call parallel initializers.

Answer (score 1):

```
@interface CoolClass : NSObject
{
  NSString *name;
}
```

You declared here an instance variable 'name'; Nowadays there is no need to declare ivars in the header file. Just use properties and make the compiler to synthesize ivar for you.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
```

Here we have a property declaration that specifies that a copy of the object should be used for assignment and that a previous value is sent a release message.

In implementation you want to synthesize your property:

```
@synthesize name = _name;
```

This code tells the compiler to generate a getter and setter for property called 'name' and use instance variable called '_name' to store value. So you have now two ivars - 'name' and '_name'.

That how init method should like like:

```
-(id)init
{
  if(self = [super init])
  {
     name = @"This is ivar declared between {}";
     _name = @"synthesized ivar";

  }
  return self;
}
```

And the dealloc:

```
-(void)dealloc
{
  [name release];
  [_name release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Why have you put [name release] twice in your dealloc?

Comment: @NickLockwood nagan's illustrating that the OP's declared two ivars.

Comment: @NickLockwood yeah, i skimmed over a few things in the OP - getting sleeeepy =)